# protect password in open source project

Tags: version-control, passwords

I was thinking about starting an open source project in github but I dont have idea how to hide my passwords that I use when I am developing! because even if I change them people can see it in the commits history when I have changed my password and then use it! now I am making some sort of webmail with PHP and I am using my personal password. What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the approach would be to isolate your passwords in configuration files and do not check in your deployment configuration files.  Instead, you would keep those on the side and apply them to your local working copy after the fact.  Many projects will have template configuration files that one can fill out to get started.

See, for example, WordPress: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-config-sample.php

Comment: yeah.. I know I have a config file where I store passwords, constants, etc.. but the problem was that I have that config file added to git so now I am just going to remove it and everything is going to work pretty well :) thanks for your help and idea I appriciate it

Comment: You may wish to git rebase or use git filter-branch to clear the passwords and such from the history. (This would be a forced update, of course, which would be a concern only if you are sharing this with others.)

Answer (score 2):

Make your code read the password from a property file that you don't commit to the git repo.